# How to display second y-axis to right of grouped bar chart data in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, charts, bar-chart, ios-charts

I am developing one activity tracker **iOS** application in which I need to show a history of steps and calories in a bar chart. I used **iOS Charts**
for this. I am able to get the grouped charts by using this but i am not able to show two seperate axis bars for steps and calories. Below is my requirment. Please suggest me how can i achive this using iOS-Charts or suggest me any other charts written in **Swift**.

[Grouped Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfDjm.png)

I wrote the code using iOS Charts library as below,

```
 func setUpDataForCharts()
{
    var weekDays = [String]()
    for i in 1 ... 7
    {
        let value = String(i)
        weekDays.append(value)
    }
    let steps = [2000, 4000, 3500, 1300, 5000, 4800, 2400]
    let calories = [20.5, 40.3, 34.0, 13.3, 50.0, 80.2, 20.0]
    setChartBarGroupDataSet(weekDays, values: steps, values2: calories)
    //setChart(weekDays, values: steps)
    barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = ChartXAxis.LabelPosition.Bottom
    barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
}

func setChartBarGroupDataSet(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double], values2: [Double]) {

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []
    var dataEntries2: [BarChartDataEntry] = []


    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }


    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(value: values2[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries2.append(dataEntry)
    }


    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: "Steps")
    let chartDataSet2 = BarChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries2, label: "Calories")

    chartDataSet2.colors =  [UIColor(hex: "3F7FD0")]

    chartDataSet.colors =  [UIColor(hex: "F53609")]

    let dataSets: [BarChartDataSet] = [chartDataSet,chartDataSet2]

    let data = BarChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSets: dataSets)

    barChartView.data = data
    barChartView.descriptionText = ""

    barChartView.rightAxis.axisMaxValue = chartDataSet2.yMax + 1.0

    barChartView.rightAxis.labelCount = chartDataSet2.valueCount


    barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    barChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true

    barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .Linear)
}
```

Out put with the above code is,

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p98T.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I updated my question with code i used. Please check it. Thanks!

Comment: Now what exactly the output get using above code?can u please share screen shot?U get only left y axis or not?

Comment: I am getting right Y-axis but that is not scaled as expected. It should be scaled based on DataSet2 assigned to it. But its not getting